# Video output gets stuck on dev/sda1 clean

Tags: boot, drivers

Running Ubuntu 18.04 
The system seems to stuck at dev/sda1. 
I can still SSH into the the system. 
I can also go into the advanced menu select recovery, and without changing anything going with resume allows the system to start normally.

I have read posts about Nvidea drivers, but I don't have a Nvidea card.
I assume the recovery boot uses some sort of default drivers is there a way to force the use of those drivers always?

Place I get stuck at

[image: Place I get stuck at]

Comment: Yes, the recovery mode uses the boot option `nomodeset`. You can add that boot option manually also for the 'normal' menu entry (in the grub menu) according to [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) and links from it. - But there is a problem behind, typical for nvidia chips/cards. Even if you have not got an nvidia card, maybe there is an nvidia chip on the motherboard or on a card with another name. Or maybe there is another graphics chip/card, that needs `nomodeset`.

Answer (score 0):

Run on terminal. In SSH edit the file "/etc/default/grub". Example:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
sudo update-grub2
```

Reboot

**You can do the same from recovery mode > root shell**

Comment: Tried it still have the same issue, but now I get a slash of purple before I get stuck. I will try tinkering with drivers next.

Comment: If you are on gdm3, can try changing display manager to lightdm.